# Custom @JsonDeserialize on a @PathVariable of @RestController

Tags: java, spring, jackson, json-deserialization, spring-restcontroller

Is possible use and custom deserializer in a @PathVariable?

```
public class MyClass {

    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    private String id;

}
```

In my RestController I have an api with 1 @PathVariable and I want use a custom deserializer.
Now when i call this api, the Id automatically goes into MyClass without using the custom deserializer.

```
@GetMapping("/try/{id}")
public void idk(@PathVariable(name = "id") MyClass myClass) {
        System.out.println(myClass);
}
```

If i use a @RequestBody work.

How do I trigger the @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)

Comment: Look at spring argument resolvers

Comment: you have a link to a specific answer?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder

Comment: In this way, I should create an instance of the class to deserialize and manually invoke the method. I want it to trigger automatically, like the jsonSerializer

Answer (score 0):

I Think you can't make it trigger automatically, you should create a mapping to mape your object or use a the solution bellow ! Else, you can call the constructor in your controller function. It depends on what do you want to do later.